# Java - Error in Enhanced for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I just started learning java. Take a look at my code for adding 1 to each element of a 2D Array using enhanced for loop. I have also attached a image of my code in eclipse.[Code for Enhanced for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Tf2.jpg)

```
package multi_array;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String args[]){
    int array[][]={{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    add_1(array);
}

public static void add_1(int a[][]){
    for(int[] a_row: a){
        for(int i: a_row){
            a_row[i]+=1;
        }
    }

    for(int[] a_row: a){
        for(int i: a_row){
            System.out.print(a_row[i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
}
```

Now when I try to run the program I get below shown error message. I have also attached the image of error message.[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj6JR.png)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at multi_array.MainClass.add_1(MainClass.java:12)
    at multi_array.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:6)
```

How can I correct this code ?

OK friends first of all sorry for my bad indention of code, after all this is my first question on stackoverflow. I got the correct result by replacing

```
for(int i: a_row){
    a_row[i]+=1;
}
```

with the code

```
for(int i=0; i<a_row.length; i++){
    a_row[i]+=1;
}
```

But I just wanted to know if I can get the desired result by using foreach loop only.

Comment: Why have you language tag spammed this question?

Comment: You should copy paste directly the code and return error instead of providing screenshots.

Comment: you are using array elements as its index which is not

Comment: read more about arrays in java, int i in your code, is the values of the array and not the index.

Comment: `for(int i: a_row){` --> `for(int i=0; i < a_row.length; ++i){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a_row` is containing all the rows of the two dimensional array and you are 
accessing `a_row[i]` where `i` value of the row and you have no `a_row[3]`
in your code change like following

```
 for(int[] a_row: a){
    for(int index=0; index < a_row.length; index++){
        a_row[index]+=1;
    }
}

for(int[] a_row: a){
    for(int i: a_row){
        System.out.print(i+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Ok I replaced a_row[i] with i only. But now I get the simple 2D array instead of adding 1 to each element of array i.e., I get numbers which I assigned to array rather than incrementing each element by 1.

Comment: I got the correct answer by just using the normal for loop as told by you. But I just wanted to know if I can do this with the help of enhanced for loop only.

Comment: what you were is to change the value of the array where it is placed and that can only be done by changing where objects[index] points to, which can only be done by using objects[index].

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that `i` has a bigger value than your array has entries.

You got this problem because you are using the actual element of the array in your loop as an index.

When I take a look at your method name I think you want just to increment every integer in your array.

You can fix your code by doing that:

```
    for(int[] a_row: a)
    {
        for(int i:a_row)
        {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
```

I think you should read how foreach-loops work. There is already a good question with nice answers on SO to this topic: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work).

Comment: Ok I replaced a_row[i] with i only. But now I get the simple 2D array instead of adding 1 to each element of array i.e., I get numbers which I assigned to array rather than incrementing each element by 1.